# Peer to peer in browser with web sockets?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket

Is it possible to write ( on latest chrome ) a web socket server in the browser using , say, chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

[socket.io](http://socket.io/) is a node.js framework for websockets.

It is possible to [use node for chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575965/is-it-possible-to-develop-google-chrome-extensions-using-node-js)

I suggest you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452889/how-to-run-a-chrome-extension-as-a-web-socket-server) too.

Comment: Npapi support is being phased out this year

Comment: However it is possible using TCp server API for chrome packaged apps